# Como avaliar se uma string está presente num array no Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Estou escrevendo um git hook para verificar se a mensagem de commit está de acordo com um array de palavras.

```
$array = @('Adiciona', 'Altera', 'Corrige', 'Refatora', 'Remove')
$msg = "Coloca coisas ao projeto."

if (!($msg.toLower().Contains($array.toLower()))){
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor "DarkGreen" "Mensagem de confirmação segue o formato."
    Write-Host "`r`nConfirmando alterações ao git.`r`n"

    return 0
}
elseif ($msg.toLower().Contains($array.toLower())){
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor "DarkRed" "Mensagem de confirmação não segue o formato!"
    Write-Host "`r`nA mensagem de confirmação precisa começar com as seguintes palavras:`r`n"
    $array | Sort
    Write-Host "`r`nAlterações não foram confirmadas ao git.`r`n"

    return 1
}
```

Pelo valor em `$msg`, é esperado que o script retorne `False` e exiba o conteúdo do `elseif`, mas ele retorna o conteúdo de `if` como se `$msg` estivesse `True`. O que estou fazendo errado?

Comment: Me desculpem se não fui bastante claro, estou desde a madrugada tentando resolver isso e nem a visão nem a cognição está funcionando a contento.

Comment: Parece que vc está verificando se uma string contém um array... não seria melhor percorrer esse array e verificar se cada elemento dele está na string?

Comment: @GabrielHardoim, obrigado pelo comentário. Fiz isso com `ForEach` e o resultado foi um retorno de `False` cinco vezes, um para cada elemento no array.

Comment: Show! teste com outra string para saber se retorna true também!

Answer (score 1):

Seu script é pequeno e simples, simplesmente abrindo o `Windows Powershell ISE` e executando passo a passo já daria pra ter entendido.

Para depurar seu script faça da seguinte forma:

1. Salve seu script localmente.
2. Adicione um ponto de interrupção com a tecla `F9`.
3. Depois execute o script com a tecla `F5`.
4. Pressione `F11` para ir rodando o programa linha a linha.

Talvez seja necessário alterar sua política de execução de scripts, então rode o script abaixo:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser
```

Do mais, o problema esta na lógica do seu `if`. Perceba que com o operador `!` você esta negando o resultado da sua condição.

Logo, a condição abaixo retorna `false`:

```
$msg.toLower().Contains($array.toLower())
```

Mas o uso do `!` na frente, inverte a lógica, fazendo assim o script entrar no seu `if`. Bastou remove-lo e pronto.